# Fit div width to text and still use max-width?

Tags: html, css

I wanna be able to use max-width and still fit box width to the text. As you see in my example below, the box width is wider than the text.

The thing is that I want the text to be centered, but left aligned, under the black mark as you see in the snippet.

Have tried with just `display:inline`, but it seems I can't use max-width with that option.

```css
.box {
  max-width:130px;
  background-color:#f00;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - (4px / 2));
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">abcdefghijk abcdefghijk<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content `abcdefghijk abcdefghijk` is longer than 130px, so your div displays at 130 and causes the content to word wrap.

Try adding a break in your content `abcdefghijk <br/> abcdefghijk` and your div will show up narrower than 130.

Comment: Right! I actually thought of that last night right when I were about to sleep and forgot it today. That actually works and is the best solution for this project since I have static text content and the width won't change on the boxes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

- place the text inside a paragraph
- give the paragraph a `display` of `inline-block`
- give the box a `text-align` of `center`

The `inline-block` paragraph will be centered inside the box.

**Working Example:**

```css
.box {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
max-width: 130px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f00;
border: 2px solid #000;
}

p {
margin: 2px;
display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>abcdefghijk abcdefghijk</p>
<div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution although the box width doesn't fit the text. So when I remove the background color it gets like a too big padding. But the main goal was to get the text centered left aligned under the mark. And that works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `<div>` with `text-align:center;`, then any text inside it will be centered with respect to the width of that container element. inline-block elements are treated as text for this purpose, so they will also be centered.

```
<div class="box">
<p>
abcdefghijk abcdefghijk
</p>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  max-width:130px;
  background-color:#f00;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  border-top: 3px solid #000;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - (4px / 2));
 }

 p {
   margin: 0;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/epe7caaL/